# If the image is present on screen - use one function, if not use another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am trying to create a bot who is evolving some units automatically (well that doesn't matter), the fact is, I have a problem: I have 2 functions evo() and scrol() my code should check if there is an image on the screen visible named mon - it should go for function evo- if it's not : go for function scrol:

I tried to do this using

```
        while True:
            scrol()
            if mon is not None:
                evo()
                break
```

and also

```
if mon is not None:
    evo()
else:
    scrol()
```

But both of these just ignoring my second function:  evo func in the while loop and scrol func on if statement

There is my full code - it works just fine without that condition, but I don't like he is scrolling even if there are present units on the screen - so it can just miss it

```
import time
import pyautogui
import win32api
import win32con
import numpy as np

time.sleep(3)

def click():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def evolve():
    evolve = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('evolve.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.8)
    if evolve is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(evolve)
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def mon():
    mon = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('mon.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.9)
    if mon is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(mon)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def autofill():
    autofill = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('autofill.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if autofill is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(autofill)
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def scroll():
    scroll = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('scroll.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if scroll is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(scroll)
        time.sleep(0.07)
        pyautogui.scroll(-4)
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def scroll2():
    scroll2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('scroll2.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if scroll2 is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(scroll2)
        time.sleep(0.07)
        pyautogui.scroll(-4)
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def yes():
    yes = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Yes.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.8)
    if yes is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(yes)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def skip():
    skip = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('skip.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.8)
    if skip is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(skip)
        click()
        time.sleep(0.1)
def ok():
    ok = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('ok.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.8)
    if ok is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(ok)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def exitt():
    exitt = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('exit.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if exitt is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(exitt)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def storage():
    storage = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('storage.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.6)
    if storage is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(storage)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def store():
    store = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('store.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if store is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(store)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def tick():
    tick = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('tick.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.9)
    if tick is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(tick)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def putin():
    putin = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('putin.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.93)
    if putin is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(putin)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def mon2():
    mon2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('mon2.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if mon2 is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(mon2)
        for a in range(1):
            time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.12))
            click()
def putout():
    putout = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('putout.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.93)
    if putout is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(putout)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def circle():
    circle = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('circle.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if circle is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(circle)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def powerup():
    powerup = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('powerup.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if powerup is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(powerup)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def evo():
        exit1()
        circle()
        powerup()
        mon()
        autofill()
        evolve()
        yes()
        skip()
        ok()
def sort():
    exitt()
    storage()
    store()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    tick()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    putin()
    mon()
    mon2()
    putout()
    exitt()
    time.sleep(1)
    click()
    circle()
    powerup()
def exit1():
    exit1 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('exit1.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if exit1 is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(exit1)
        click()
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
def scrol():
    scrol2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('scrol2.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
    if scrol2 is not None:
        scroll2()
    else:
        scroll()

# while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):

for count in range(40):
    unexistent = False
    if not unexistent:

        evo()
        scrol()
                
        tess = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('tess.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.7)
        if tess is not None:
            unexistent = True

    if unexistent:
        sort()
        unexistent = False
```

Comment: I don't see a `while True: ` loop anywhere in your code. In this loop, you check `if mon is not None`. Do you ever update `mon`? If you don't, it'll always have the value it started out with.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I gave my code without that loop
I putted in just 
evo() and scrol() without conditions

Comment: I also tried to declare that mon as global variable - so it got the value for sure

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your function mon is not returning anything. Also you ask for mon, not mon(). As mon is defined as a function and not changed, it is never None and the condition is always fulfilled.

Maybe you want the return value of mon? There is nothing returned in your example. Or you have an image called the same name as your function? Then just rename the image.

Comment: It is returning, since it's working fine without any loop

Comment: I have mon variable and mon() function - rename does not help

Comment: It is not returning any value. I expect some image. 
So you overwrite your variable with the function. What do you get when you print(type(mon))? Is that your image or a function?

When you check if mon is None, it sees that mon is a function.

Comment: Ok. So I changed in my def mon() variable's name into mons, it shouldn't be a problem with this anymore.
My mons variable keep the coordinates of the mon.png image.
prin(type(mons))     <class 'NoneType'>
My whole evo() func is all about this: click that image, then click another image then another ..... etc. And all that in the for loop. scrol() is a function just scroll down to see more

Comment: https://youtu.be/v3Nq17JyiXE - there is a quick review of what my bot is doing. As you can see it keep scrolling everytime after he evolved one unit. I wanna make it scroll only if there are no available units to evolve